# How to SSH to and connect back to original network?

Tags: linux, ssh, nmap

Once I’ve connected to my Linux Machine(B) over the internet from my current PC(A), is there a way to run software on that machine(B) on the local one(A) so that it uses the original network. For example to scan the original network using NMap that is installed on the remote machine.

I’ve prepared an beautiful image to illustrate what I mean.

[image]

Any links or search terms you could provide would be extremely helpful as I’m not quite sure what to Google for after getting a series of dead ends.

Comment: Also i'm not quite sure what the technology i'm looking for is called past SSH so if anyone could clean up the title/question that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't run `nmap` on machine A directly?

Comment: The purple text in your image is completely illegible on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user55325's answer is the correct answer, I will not quibble with that. But, just for the sake of completeness, let me stress you can achieve the same result with `OpenSSH` alone.

This is so much easier to do in Linux/Unix that my advice to you is, **if** your machine A is a Windows PC, to install a Linux Virtual Machine onto your Windows PC, and then follow the instructions that I am about to suggest for setting up a connection between two Unices. Any hypervisor will do, but generally VirtualBox is quite user-friendly.

Google is full of guides about how to do this, I just searched for `ssh vpn`. The first guide is [Ubuntu-specific](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN); as a matter of taste, being a dedicated Debian/Arch Linux user, I would suggest [the Arch-Linux way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH) (the Arch Linux documentation, and especially its wiki, is one of the best around, possibly rivaled only by OpenBSD). Lastly, for a more distro-agnostic introduction, I would suggest [Bohdi Zazen's excellent intro](http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH).

Like I said, the previous answer is excellent, I am adding this for the  sake of completeness. Here and there in the intros mentioned, you will find claims that this way, or user55325's, is better. It is mostly a matter of taste, IMHO.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, to follow up I'm trying to do this from a jail broken iPhone, once I set up the vpn the iPhone would be the server and the Linux machine as the client. I SSH to the Linux box and then it connects to the iPhone as the server? Is there anything further I need to do to get the Linux box using the iPhone's original network?

Comment: @Jacob2471 For both VPN and ssh: the connection is initiated by the Linux machine. You can do this either manually (connecto to the Linux machine, give a few commands), or automatically (every time at boot, and restart whenever the connection fails). And: no, there is nothing else you need to do, except, perhaps, if you want to use ssh instead of vpn, and you want to make this a permanent connection, then use **autossh**, which automatically detects when your ssh connection has dropped, and restarts it so as to keep it permanently on.

Comment: Is it also possible to do it a longer way (that makes sense in my head), where i SSH into the Linux box from Mobile terminal, then set up the VPN connect to the server that I configured on the iPhone manually so that it links to the iPhones LAN?

Comment: @Jacob2471 Yes, sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

SSH by itself is not enough. You could set up a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to do this - [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) is free and supports all major operating systems. You would [set up the server](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) on machine A and the client on machine B, then you have a way for B to communicate securely with anything on A's local network.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, is OpenVPN done via the command line? Would the Linux version work on a jail broken iPhone?

Comment: It looks like there is an OpenVPN client available for the iPhone in the Apple app store, no need to jailbreak. [Here](http://louwrentius.com/setup-a-vpn-on-your-iphone-with-openvpn-and-linux.html) is a guide on how to set it up.

Comment: But i want to bring the Linux box to the iPhones server? Doesnt this mean I need the iPhone to be the server and the linux box the client?

Comment: So you want to be able to reach devices on the iPhone's local network from your Windows machine? Can you be more specific about what you want to do and why?

Comment: From a Kali machine not windows, I want to run NMAP through the connection.

Comment: It looks like (an old version of) nmap is available in Cydia. That might be your best option, instead of trying to set up a VPN server on the iPhone.